# How to replace specific word on a large text in a column using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

I am looking to replace values in a particular column.
For example the following column values

```
desc
----------
Test1 words = 30 have so much words = 20 over 60 words +
Test2 words = 30 have so much words = 20 over 60 words +
Test3 words = 30 have so much words = 20 over 60 words +
Test4 words = 30 have so much words = 20 over 60 words +
```

should be (replacing ords = 20 with Alpha = 20)

result:

```
desc
----------
Test1 words = 30 have so much Alpha = 20 over 60 words +
Test2 words = 30 have so much Alpha = 20 over 60 words +
Test3 words = 30 have so much Alpha = 20 over 60 words +
Test4 words = 30 have so much Alpha = 20 over 60 words +
```

I have tried the following :

update table set desc = REPLACE('words = 20', 'words', 'Alpha') where ;

This results to :

Alpha = 20  instead of the entire row.
however, how can I keep the rest of the text just change "words = 20" but still keep the rest of the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement:

```
update table set desc = REPLACE('words = 20', 'words', 'Alpha') where ...;
```

is replacing 'words' in the *fixed string* 'words = 20`; it isn't acting on the existing column value you at all.

You could do:

```
update table set desc = REPLACE(desc, 'words = 20', 'Alpha = 20') where ...;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=273c5be89ec5c433cc1333cdeffe8fa8) (using valid table and column names).

If you want to replace *all* occurrences of 'words', not just 'words = 20', then remove the `= 20` from both arguments; but from your attempt I think you want it to be more targetted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform the `replace` on the original string, not on `'words = 20':

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET    desc = REPLACE(desc, 'words', 'Alpha')
```

Side note:
I'm guessing these aren't the real names in your table, but `desc` is a reserved word in SQL. If it's really the column's name, you need to escape it with double quotes (i.e., `"desc"`).